# Auto Height of tabitem wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I'd like to create a tabcontrol through code with 2 tabs . I used the code below :

```
                TabControl tb = new TabControl();
                tb.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
                tb.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
                tb.VerticalContentAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
                tb.HorizontalContentAlignment =  System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
                ressource_design.initialiserTabControl(tb);
                tb.Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 10, 10);
                TabItem ti1 = new TabItem();
                ti1.Header = ServicesLangue.RM.GetString("CONTENU_ACCUEIL_LISTE_SAS");
                ti1.Content = _listeSAS;
                tb.Items.Add(ti1);

                TabItem ti2 = new TabItem();
                ti2.Header = ServicesLangue.RM.GetString("CONTENU_ACCUEIL_TBSM");
                ti2.Content = _tbsm;
                tb.Items.Add(ti2);

                this.DockPrincipal.Children.Add(tb);
```

But the height of my tabitem is the height of the children control. This is driving me crazy !

I've tried to add the code below in my child control:

```
Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Path=ActualWidth}"
                Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Path=ActualHeight}"
```

But this makes le child control too big !

Note: I have the same problem with the Accordion.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you're creating the control in the code-behind instead of in XAML?

Comment: Please provide the complete code i.e. XAML as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove any static Height and Width you set in XAML or Code behind.
HorizontalContentAlignment and VerticalContentAlignment are by default set to Stretch.

Comment: Works, I had to remove also Height and Width properties in the children Usercontrols. Thanks !

Comment: Great !!
So  try to use Grid container to arrange your controls and avoid setting static Height and Width as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If your DockPrincipal is a Dockpanel and is filling your whole form, you could set LastChildFill="True"